# Looking for a MIDI note re-mapper VST.

Tags: midi, vst

I write drum tracks in Guitar Pro using standard General Midi note numbers (#35/#36 kick, #38/#40 snare, etc.), then use MIDI-Yoke (a virtual MIDI port) to redirect the notes to VSTHost (a tiny standalone VST host), where I can listen to the song before moving it to my DAW.

My problem is that the drum VST that I use has note mappings that differ from the standard GM mapping (say, my kickdrum is #40 and my snare is #55). I'm looking for a no-frills, intuitive MIDI VST that allows me to re-map the notes one by one, and save those maps.

Comment: While this doesn't *directly* answer your question (as it's not a VST), you can use the MIDI transformation features in MIDI-OX to change the mappings of notes. It is saveable and gets the job done, although I personally think it's a bit awkward to work with.

Comment: +1 for MIDI-OX, but I quite like it.Most sequencers should be able to do this too. Logic Studio most certainly can.

Comment: Can't you export the midi from guitar pro and import it on the DAW?

Comment: @JohnnyBigoode I want to be able to do this in real-time. MIDI-OX is great, but too versatile for its own good - its difficulty of use really overwhelms its benefits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this help you?
http://www.midikarval.net/MidiMapper.html

Comment: Please add some more information about the VST here to make your answer more complete and also to make the information searchable on this site.

Comment: From the looks of it, this is exactly what I need. I'll look into it - thanks a ton!